# How to put this in a E/R diagram?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

Have a simple question, but I think I am overthinking it. I need to make an E/R diagram out of this:

> Substantial fees are due every calendar year. Fee payments must be
>   made via a bank transfer, mentioning the member number and the
>   membership year it applies to. The database should store the date of
>   payment.

I am ignoring calendar year, as I think it is not relevant for the E/R diagram. I have an entity called `"Members"` which I like to `"Fee"` via *"payed via the relationship *(diamond symbol)* a bank transfer"*.

Now, my question is: should `"member number"` and `"membership"` be part of the `"fee"` entity or the `"member"` entity? Or both? Because I am thinking to add a new **relationship** to `"fee"` giving it the name ***"consists of"*** and then link "member number" and "membership", but I don't know whether that's good or not.

And what to do with the last sentence? *"The database should store the date of payment."*? Can I ignore it?

Comment: Is Member_number going to change over time for a member or is it the unique identifier (PK) of a member?

Comment: It does not say anything about changing, so I assume it's a primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description I got:

- You have entity sets `Members` and `Payments`
- `Members` are identified by a `member_number`
- `Payments` have attributes `date`, `amount` and `membership_year`

Obviously, we also need:

- `Payments` have an attribute `amount`

How are we going to identify `Payments`? No combination of the listed attributes are uniquely identifying in my opinion. A `Member` *could* make two identical `Payments` on the same date with the same amount, for the same membership year, e.g. if they accidentally only paid half of the annual fee at first then made a second payment to correct.

Let's introduce a surrogate key:

- `Payments` are identified by a `payment_id`

We also need a relationship between the two entity sets:

- Each `Payment` is associated with a single `Member`
- Each `Member` can make multiple `Payments`

We can put this info into an ER diagram:

[image: Member payments ER diagram]

To derive a table diagram, Chen's original method implemented every entity relation (entity key and attributes) and relationship relation (relationship keys (i.e. related entity keys) and relationship attributes) as separate tables:

[image: Member payments table diagram 1]

However, it's common practice to denormalize tables with the same primary key:

[image: Member payments table diagram 2]

I recommend you study Chen's paper `The Entity-Relationship Model - Toward a Unified View of Data`. Codd's paper `A Relational Model of Data for Large Shared Databanks` provides valuable background.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you very much! I have a question though: I had the relations membership year and member number linked to "paid", the diamond. Would that be wrong?

Comment: `Membership year` and `member number` are attributes, not relations. Since `Paid` and `Payment` have the same primary key, the attribute / functional dependency `payment_id -> membership_year` can be implemented in either table / relation. As for `member_number`, it's an essential component of the relationship, but IRL the model would probably be extended to capture member name, gender, birthday, etc so we need to have a separate entity set identified by `member_number`.

Comment: I meant attribute, yes, sorry. Thanks for the explanation. Appreciate it a lot!